# Android: Force landscape orientation but allow rotation

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to force my Android app into lanscape orientation. I managed to do that by adding `screenOrientation` in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
  <activity android:name="SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

or by adding the following line in the `onCreate` function of my only `Activity`:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The problem is that both the solutions above disables rotation. How do I force landscape but allow rotation? I want to be able to rotate the phone 180 degrees. From landscape to the other landscape.

Comment: Do you mean default to landscape, but allow portrait?

Comment: You can let the user start the activity in any mode and detect if he is in landscape or portrait and then handle with an alert to force him landscape.

Comment: No. I want to be able to rotate the phone 180 degrees. From landscape to landscape. @Simon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to set the `android:screenOrientation` attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml to `sensorLandscape`

Answer (score 5):

Refer to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

For your activity, set the attribute as sensorLandscape

This enables to have the screen in landscape orientation, but can use the sensor to change which direction the screen is facing. Corresponds to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE.

**Code sample**

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```